# How to use my Class with PList in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a Class for handling my data in my project, and now I need to store the data.
I'd like to use a Plist but I'm a bit unsure of how to start.
My class is pretty simple - 6 pieces of data, flat (no hierarchy).

I want my app to start with no data, so can I assume that I should create the PList programmatically once the User creates their first piece of data? (That is, don't create a .plist file in 'Supporting Files' prior to distribution?)

Then, when the app starts the next time, read the data and create an NSMUtableArray array of Class instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a property list, all you need to do is use appropriate types (i.e. those that support the property list format: NSData, NSString, NSDictionary, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray), store them in a single container, and tell the containing object to write itself to a file. To read the data, you can initialize that same type using a path. For example:

```
// writing some data to a property list
NSString *somePath = ... // replace ... with the path where you want to store the plist file
NSMutableDictionary myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[myDict setObject:@"Caleb" forKey:@"name"];
[myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:240] forKey:@"cholesterolOrIQ"];
[myDict writeToFile:somePath atomically:YES];

// reading the file again
NSDictionary *readDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:somePath];
```

Comment: This seems straightforward but what if I'm using types like 'int' 'BOOL' 'UIColor' - plus, it's all in an NSMutableArray? Do I need to use NSCoding, Archiving, etc?

Comment: Start by reading [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD) and [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1). For non-property list types like UIColor, you can either encode them using a type that supports plists, like NSString, NSNumber, or NSData, or you can use a different format. Archiving is a good way to go then.

Comment: I found this link to be the simplest description yet: [nscoding sample](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/nscoding) and with minimal coding I've gotten it working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to simple save an NSArray or NSDictionary to disk. Caleb's answer goes into detail there so I won't repeat it, other than to say you might have to convert a non-compatible object like NSColor to an property list object like NSData. It's up to you to do this each time you save or load your data.

NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver give you a little more control over the process, but work pretty much the same way. You provide (or get back) a plist compatible root object (usually an NSDictionary) that contains your data. I recommend creating a dictionary that includes your data structure as well as an arbitrary number (your app's build number is a good choice) to use as a version indicator. This way if you ever update your data model you can easily determine if you need to do anything to convert it to the new version.

If you're putting your own objects into the data file, look into NSCoding. The protocol gives you two methods using NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver to save and restore your data. This is by far the most straightforward approach if your data model consists of anything more than a few simple strings and numbers, since you're dealing with your own native objects. In your case, you would have your data class implement NSCoding and use the NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver methods to encode your six instance variables. When it's time to save or load, pack the instance of your class into an NSDictionary (along with a versioning number as I mentioned above) and call NSKeyedArchiver's `archiveRootObject:toFile:`. Your save an load methods deal only with your own data object, which makes things easy for you. The common pitfall to watch out for here is if your custom data object contains other custom object. This is fine, but you have to make sure every object that's going to be saved has its own NSCoding implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Two things you can do:

Use NSUserDefaults:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

The objectForKey method is the one you want to use to store your class. But, as pointed out in the comments, this shouldn't really be used for storing lots of user data; it's best for saving preferences.

For storing more data, you might want to look at Core Data. It's more complex, but should be better suited to your needs. Here's a tutorial on it:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/

Neither of these seems best for your simple application, but I leave this answer up since it gives alternatives for saving data to the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks. The User will be creating multiple instances of the Class by adding items to a list and then setting properties for each item, so I'll need to store an array or dictionary.

Comment: If this does work out, you should click the checkmark. It tells other SO users that this question has been answer satisfactorily. :)

Comment: Still have questions! Not sure how to read/write an array of class instances to/from the Plist.

Comment: You're not using a PList. If you use NSUserDefaults, it will take care of storing the object for you. No need to worry about how it does it. :)

Comment: NSUserDefaults are for application settings. Storing user data in it is just being lazy an non-scaleable.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is basically "How do I use a property list?".

Comment: My reading of the question was, "How do I save class data?" Yours is a good answer, better than mine since it is less complex. +1 to it.

Comment: NSUserDefaults are for storing preferences, not user data. I'd also stay away from Core Data if your needs are simple. It will definitely add complexity to a project that may not be needed if a plist will do the job.