# Objective-C write array to .plist

Tags: objective-c, plist

I have pre-filled information except one string, which will be input by the user. I currently am able to read only a single key with this code:

```
#define defaultValue @"Someone"
#define myKey @"Event"

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *val = [defaults stringForKey:myKey];
if (val == nil) val = defaultValue;
[myTextField setStringValue:val];
```

I write it with this code:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *val;

    // Get the new value from the textfield

    val = [myTextField stringValue];

    if ([val isEqualToString:defaultValue]) {
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:myKey];
    } else {
        [defaults setObject:val forKey:myKey];
    }
```

What I really need is to write an array to a .plist like this, and have the 5th string able to be a user input string. How can I do this?:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Event/key>
    <dict>
        <key>Staff Meeting</key>
        <string>Friday Feb 3rd, 2012 </string>
        <key>Contact</key>
        <string>events@whitehouse.gov</string>
        <key>URL</key>
        <string>http://www.whitehouse.gov</string>
        <key>Status</key>
        <string>ATTENDING</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Mr. President</string>         <------- USER TEXT INPUT
        <key>Signature</key>
        <data>
        20001
        </data>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use my Class with PList in objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087592/how-to-use-my-class-with-plist-in-objective-c)

Comment: @Caleb, my hierachy isn't flat, is it?

Comment: So? A property list can represent an entire graph of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example to create the structure you want.

```
-(void)saveData:(NSString*)someParam
{
    NSMutableDictionary *rootObj = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];

    NSDictionary *innerDict;

    NSString *staffMeetingValue;
    NSString *contactValue;
    NSString *nameValue;

    staffMeetingValue = @"Friday Feb 3rd, 2012";
    contactValue = @"events@whitehouse.gov";
    nameValue = someParam;

    innerDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects: staffMeetingValue, contactValue, nameValue, nil]
        forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Staff Meeting", @"Contact", @"Name"]];

    [rootObj setObject:innerDict forKey:@"Event"];

    id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:(id)rootObj
        format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
}
```

For other info see [Creating Property Lists Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html)

Hope it helps.

P.S. You have to add keys and objects for other tags. I skipped them for the sake of simplicity.

**Edit:**

This is a simple example how to do that. `staffMeetingValue` and `contactValue` values are hardcoded but you can pass it as parameters as `nameValue`.

```
-(void)saveDataWithName:(NSString*)nameValue staffMeting:(NSString*)staffMetingValue contact:(NSString*)contactValue {    
    // previous stuff here    
}
```